# padx values seem to affect the arrangement of tkinter Frames

Tags: python, tkinter, layout, frames

So have a look at the below image.
[image: tk Window]

On this window I have 3 Frames which are actually inherited from tk.Frame (i don't think that makes a difference here).

The first frame is at the up top which has 3 Buttons and 1 more will be added in the later parts of the program.Second Frame consists of those 9 buttons in a 3x3 layout.
and 3rd frame has a label (i actually want two labels down there, one to the left and one to the right.)

What I want to achieve is keep the first frame as is, the 3x3 layout in the second frame need to be in the center (horizontally at least), and the labels in third frames, one to be at the left most and other one (haven't added it yet) to absolute right.

I have observed that whenever I change the `padx` (and even `ipadx`) values for any button in first frame, it seems to change the position of that 3x3 layout. Like when I increase `padx` for Stats Button, it slides both the 3x3 layout and bottom most label to the right. Which i feel like is weird because padding of something in a whole different frame altogether should not affect the layout of any other frame.

Here is the MCVE for the issue:

```
import tkinter as tk

class MenuBar(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root)


class StBar(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root)


class MidSpace(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root)


class MainApp:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.StBar = StBar(self.root)
        self.MenuBar = MenuBar(self.root)
        self.MidSpace = MidSpace(self.root)

        self.root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=3)
        self.root.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=55)
        self.root.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=2)

        self.MenuBar.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.MidSpace.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.StBar.grid(row=2, column=0)

        self.htpb = tk.Button(self.MenuBar, text='How To Play', width=14,
                          bg='#00f', fg='#fff')
        self.htpb.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, ipady=5, sticky=tk.N + tk.S)

        self.statb = tk.Button(self.MenuBar, text='Stats', width=14,
                           bg='#00f', fg='#fff')
        self.statb.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, ipady=5, sticky=tk.N + tk.S)

        self.resb = tk.Button(self.MenuBar, text='Results', width=14,
                          bg='#00f', fg='#fff')
        self.resb.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10, ipady=5, sticky=tk.N + tk.S)

        self.stLabel = tk.Label(self.StBar,
                            text='Some single line text here', bg='#00f',
                            fg='#fff', font=('roboto', 13))
        self.stLabel.pack(anchor=tk.W)

        self.b1 = tk.Button(self.MidSpace, text='  ',
                        bg='#da5', fg='#250038',
                        font=('roboto', 20), width=2, height=1)
        self.b2 = tk.Button(self.MidSpace, text='  ',
                        bg='#745', fg='#380601',
                        font=('roboto', 20), width=2, height=1)
        self.b3 = tk.Button(self.MidSpace, text='  ',
                        bg='#da5', fg='#250038',
                        font=('roboto', 20), width=2, height=1)
        self.b4 = tk.Button(self.MidSpace, text='  ',
                        bg='#745', fg='#380601',
                        font=('roboto', 20), width=2, height=1)
        self.b5 = tk.Button(self.MidSpace, text='  ',
                        bg='#da5', fg='#250038',
                        font=('roboto', 20), width=2, height=1)
        self.b6 = tk.Button(self.MidSpace, text='  ',
                        bg='#745', fg='#380601',
                        font=('roboto', 20), width=2, height=1)
        self.b7 = tk.Button(self.MidSpace, text='  ',
                        bg='#da5', fg='#250038',
                        font=('roboto', 20), width=2, height=1)
        self.b8 = tk.Button(self.MidSpace, text='  ',
                        bg='#745', fg='#380601',
                        font=('roboto', 20), width=2, height=1)
        self.b9 = tk.Button(self.MidSpace, text='  ',
                        bg='#da5', fg='#250038',
                        font=('roboto', 20), width=2, height=1)

        self.b1.grid(row=0, column=0, ipadx=40, ipady=40)
        self.b2.grid(row=0, column=1, ipadx=40, ipady=40)
        self.b3.grid(row=0, column=2, ipadx=40, ipady=40)
        self.b4.grid(row=1, column=0, ipadx=40, ipady=40)
        self.b5.grid(row=1, column=1, ipadx=40, ipady=40)
        self.b6.grid(row=1, column=2, ipadx=40, ipady=40)
        self.b7.grid(row=2, column=0, ipadx=40, ipady=40)
        self.b8.grid(row=2, column=1, ipadx=40, ipady=40)
        self.b9.grid(row=2, column=2, ipadx=40, ipady=40)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    win = tk.Tk()
    win.geometry('1360x710')
    win.title('TicTacToe - pssolanki')
    win.wm_geometry("+0+0")
    win.configure(bg='#fff')
    MainApp(win)
    win.mainloop()
```

**If ya need to know anything else either let me know or check the code at** [Github Repository](https://github.com/pssolanki111/TicTacToe-gui)

Any help or suggestion is appreciated. You can also suggest a better title for the question 'cause I couldn't think of anything better.

Thank YOU :)

Comment: Please try to condense this code down to a complete [mcve]. It's hard for us to know how to stitch these blocks of code together in order to run it.

Comment: @Bryan I have edited the question as suggested. Please check now.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using grid for the top-most frames? Do you plan to put other widgets in additional columns?

Comment: Not really. I used grid just so I would be able to do grid_rowconfigure() because I will need the heights of those frames different (ofcourse MenuBar and StBar will have less heights than MidSpace 'cause midspace will have those 3x3 buttons in there). and also I will need these 3 frames to take up the complete width and height of the window (width has to be same for all of them - equal to the width of root window)
So As long as this condition is satisfied, I can definitely go with pack() as well (which I know is actually recommended for frames).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that all three frames are in a single column. Since a column has uniform width in a grid, if you make the top frame wider it makes the whole column wider, and that affects how the second and third frame appear.

My advice would be to use `pack` for the three top-level frames. I would pack `MenuBar` along the top, `StBar` along the bottom, and then `MidSpace` in the middle.

Comment: well, That actually explains one of my prolonged questions about grid GeoManager.

I'ma try that rn.

Comment: That Worked, Thank YOU. I just had to add anchor to achieve what I actually wanted to, and it went fine.